# Get user profile (V2) in Microsoft Flow - How to use select query

Tags: rest, odata, azure-logic-apps, power-automate, office365connectors

In Microsoft Flow, I'm trying to retrieve a custom field in a user profile. I'm using the "**Get user profile (V2)**" operation and I want to specify the custom field in the Query field.
No matter how I construct the Query the operation returns this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Query option '$select' was specified more than once, but it must be specified at most once.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "785b1a00-e298-494f-95ad-af979856cbf4",
      "date": "2018-01-05T13:41:46"
    }
  }
}
```

What syntax should I use to get, e.g. the field 'TestField'?

I guess the value in the Query field is added to the OData Query created by the operation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,
Peter Rundqvist

Comment: I am getting the same response as well when trying any combination of field  names. It is still in 'Preview' so may be the reason why it's broken. Leaving the $select field blank will work or just use V1 to get all fields and pick which field you need in the next action.